# How to implement waterfall layout for UICollectionView in swift that varies their height according to fetched remote images?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, pinterest, waterfall

What I have gathered from my research for waterfall layout is that we need to know the heights in advance to do prepareLayout. But if we wait to fetch remote images and then find their size and do prepareLayout, then there will be a lot of delay. But I see a lot of apps using this layout with remote images such as Pinterest, Microsoft Delve, etc. I saw a lot of waterfall layout examples in swift. But they use the images from assets.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the size from image, and if no image is available, you can set the image.

Once you will get the image from backend, you can call reloadData or reloadItemAtIndexPath, in both cases the layout method will be called for cells.

You can also try it with overriding layoutSubviews method and Flowlayout methods.

Comment: Is it a good practice to send the image sizes along with the API response?

Comment: that is not required, because once the image will be downloaded, then user can get the image size at runtime instead of sending it in api response.